# Used Named Credentials to Call another Web Service

Tags: apex, webservices, namedcredentials

Hello everyone I have a named credential for Microsoft Access Control Service, this named credential is Authenticated, so I need the token to call another web service that isn't in the same domain for example the URL to login is this : https://login.microsoftonline.com/********/v2.0 and I need to call a web service from https://*********.org/api/SalesforceLAAM, both are different domains, to call the second web service I need the token generated for the named credential, Have any of you had this situation before?

Comment: @identigral, no is not the same case, because they are making the callout the same domain, in this case are different.

Comment: See last paragraph of the referenced answer

Comment: Hi  @identigral, did you know how to make the call out? Because, I can't find the way to make the call out.

Comment: The referenced answer shows how to make the callout. The token is automagically injected by the Named Credential if your `.org/api/..` API supports a standard authorization protocol.

Comment: OK, but when I maked the callout this is the endpoint that is trying to reach Endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXX/v2.0/https://YYYYYYYYYYY.org/api/SalesforceLAAM, Method=GET, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=Method: Bearer, I think is wrong because are to different domains

Comment: Have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294644/setting-up-named-credential-for-external-rest-api-with-oauth2-0